# gojs with vuejs and webpack

Tags: vue.js, webpack, gojs

I'm trying to set up a simple gojs diagram into vuejs + webpack. 
I installed gojs with npm and imported it on my project in the main.js file: `import go from 'gojs'`
Now my problem is how to make things work in the component implementation, that's the code of the component Diagram.vue:

```
<template>
   <div id="myDiagramDiv" style="width:300px; height:300px;"></div>
</template>

<script>
   export default {
      name: 'Diagram', 
      data: function () {
         return {
            nodeDataArray: [
               {key:1, text:"Alpha"},
               {key:2, text:"Beta"}
            ],
            linkDataArray: [
               {from:1, to:2}
            ]
         }
      },
      methods: {
         getUnits: function(){
            var $ = go.GraphObject.make;
            myDiagram = $(go.Diagram, "myDiagramDiv");
            myDiagram.model = new go.GraphLinksModel(nodeDataArray, linkDataArray);
         }
      },
      mounted: function(){
         this.getUnits();
      }
}
</script>
```

it compiles without error but I can only see a white empty box...

Comment: Try using `this.nodeDataArray` and `this.linkDataArray`

Comment: Try to use linter. It will show you error without a stackoverflow question.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't initialized the **Diagram** yet.  That is typically done by calling `go.GraphObject.make(go.Diagram, theHTMLDivElement, { . . . options . . .})`

There is a complete but simple example of using GoJS in a Vue.js framework at https://gojs.net/latest/samples/vue.html.

Answer (score 0):

> ow my problem is how to make things work in the component implementation

There is an official (made by the GoJS team) VueJS + Webpack + GoJS project in the gojs-projects github, that you can use as an example: https://github.com/NorthwoodsSoftware/GoJS-projects